# IntelliJ Ultimate - groovy config - What is Path to configscript?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I have zip downloaded groovy (groovy-3.0.0-rc-3 [URL](http://groovy-lang.org/download.html)) and unziped into a directory.  I can run groovy scripts by saying the following after adding $GROOVY_HOME/bin to my path.

```
groovy ex1.groovy
```

where `ex1.groovy` has the following one line:

`["Rod", "Carlos", "Chris"].findAll{it.size() < 4}.each{println it}`

So I know it is working, but when I try to run the same script in IntelliJ Ultimate, I get an error saying

```
Information:Groovyc: While compiling groovy1:org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
C:\p\groovy-3.0.0-rc-3\conf\groovy-starter.conf: 1: Unexpected input: '#' @ line 1, column 1.
   ## Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
```

So the file I specified for **File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment, Compiler > Groovy Compiler** dialog, the field name was `Path to configscript` was not correct.  I used the file `$GROOVY_HOME/conf/groovy-starter.conf`.

But when I remove it I get another error which basically indicates the IntelliJ doesn't (yet) know where to look for the install files.

```
Information:Groovyc: While compiling groovy1:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Unable to load class org.apache.groovy.jaxb.extensions.JaxbExtensions due to missing dependency javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext
```

I searched for a solution and found IntelliJ's documentation was basically useless (restating the obvious).

- [Groovy Compiler settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/groovy-compiler.html)
- [Getting started with Groovy (in IntelliJ)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-groovy.html#)

My thought is that by passing the correctly formatted file to the groovy compiler, the other files needed to run a Groovy script will be found.

Thanks, in advance, for any help.

Comment: See http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/tools-groovyc.html for the `-configscript` option descripion. You don't need to specify it for the compiler to work in most cases. The second error seems to occur because of your Java and Groovy versions mismatch. Can you check if it works with Java 8?

Comment: Try 2.5.x version instead.

Comment: I'm currently using Java 8.  My gut feeling is that the problem is due to having a non-normal install/setup.  I'm on a work machine without admin and Java (1.8.0) happened to be installed, but groovy wasn't so I put it in `c:\myapps\groovy-3.0.0-rc-3`, I wonder what version of Java was included with IntelliJ IDE, let me check that.  That version is 11.0.5, that gives me something to try.

Comment: You can't use the JetBrains Runtime bundled with the IDE for development. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html which describes how to download and install the JDK for your projects.

Comment: 2020-12-01 I'm having this same question....  Hopefully I'll find the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get IntelliJ to run `groovy` files, I needed to properly configure groovy inside IntelliJ.

Through some experimentation found that a file is included in the groovy zipfile distribution that can be used.  The file is `groovy/config/groovy-starter.conf`

So if the groovy zip file was unzipped to the directory `$HOME/.apps/groovy` then the config is located at `$HOME/.apps/groovy/config/groovy-starter.conf`

After using this file as the config file, I was able to run *.groovy files inside IntelliJ Ultimate and they ran correctly.

Also see the Intellij documentation at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-groovy.html

Below is the full java command that was used when I selected File | Run

```
C:\p\jdk1.8.0_271\bin\java.exe -Dtools.jar=C:\p\jdk1.8.0_271\lib\tools.jar -Dgroovy.home=C:\p\groovy-3.0.6 -Dgroovy.starter.conf=C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\conf\groovy-starter.conf "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=57171:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-3.0.6.jar org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter --conf C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\conf\groovy-starter.conf --main groovy.ui.GroovyMain --classpath .;C:\Play\groovy-try2\out\production\groovy-try2;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\ant-1.10.8.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\ant-antlr-1.10.8.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\ant-junit-1.10.8.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\ant-launcher-1.10.8.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\bsf-2.4.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\commons-cli-1.4.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\commons-logging-1.2.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\gpars-1.2.1.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-ant-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-astbuilder-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-bsf-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-cli-commons-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-cli-picocli-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-console-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-datetime-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-dateutil-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-docgenerator-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-groovydoc-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-groovysh-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-jaxb-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-jmx-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-json-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-jsr223-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-macro-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-nio-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-servlet-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-sql-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-swing-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-templates-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-test-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-test-junit5-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-testng-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-xml-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\groovy-yaml-3.0.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\ivy-2.5.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jackson-annotations-2.11.2.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jackson-core-2.11.2.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jackson-databind-2.11.2.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.11.2.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jansi-1.18.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\javaparser-core-3.16.1.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jcommander-1.78.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jline-2.14.6.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jsp-api-2.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\jsr166y-1.7.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\junit-4.13.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\junit-jupiter-api-5.7.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\junit-jupiter-engine-5.7.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\junit-platform-commons-1.7.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\junit-platform-engine-1.7.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\junit-platform-launcher-1.7.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\multiverse-core-0.7.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\opentest4j-1.2.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.1.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\qdox-1.12.1.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\snakeyaml-1.26.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\ST4-4.1.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\testng-7.3.0.jar;C:\p\groovy-3.0.6\lib\xstream-1.4.13.jar --encoding=UTF-8 C:\Play\groovy-try2\src\hello2.groovy
```