# What Groovy plugin makes File | New | Groovy work (inside of IntelliJ Ultimate)?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy

I've installed

1. IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.5 (Ultimate Edition)
2. Groovy 4 Groovy Version: 4.0.15

I'm following the IntelliJ instructions at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-groovy.html

Which shows this:
[image]

When I try this, however, Groovy does not show up.  Below is what I see:

[image]

The website says:

> Before you start working with Groovy, make sure the Groovy plugin is enabled in IntelliJ IDEA.

so I checked that and see that it is enabled.

[image]

**Is this the groovy plugin that is needed?  What am I missing?**

Years ago I asked how to do this and that post is at
[IntelliJ Ultimate - groovy config - What is Path to configscript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849358/intellij-ultimate-groovy-config-what-is-path-to-configscript)

### To reproduce problem (Approach #1)

In approach #1, I tried creating a new Groovy Project from IntelliJ but as I stated earlier the choice of Groovy does not appear as an option for me.

### To reproduce problem (Approach #2)

To reproduce this problem using an existing Maven/Java project I created an sample program using:

1. Create sample Maven project

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=helloworld -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

2. Open the project (just created) inside of IntelliJ
3. Navigate to the `App` class (aka the *Main* for this project) and that same package as Main, right click the package name and select **New | File**, and notice that you don't have Create Groovy as a choice.

### Submitted issue to JetBrains/IntelliJ

I've also submitted a question about this to IntelliJ technical support.

See https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/5849227

Comment: As I can see the Groovy framework is not added to the project if we generate a project with this archetype. Please refer to https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/getting-started-with-groovy.html#add_groovy_support on how to enable Groovy for your project

Comment: In your case, you can update pom.xml file as per https://groovy.github.io/gmaven/groovy-maven-plugin

Comment: Does your maven project have a groovy folder under `src/main/groovy`?  If you add that it might trigger IntelliJ to recognize that you want to have groovy files.  I seem to remember I kinda needed groovy files before Intellij will wake up and give me those options.  I know with Gradle configuring the `groovy` plugin also tells Intellij this ia `groovy` project.  So the suggestion of adding the groovy-maven-plugin is probably the right move.

Comment: @chubbsondubs, at the time I asked the question, I did not have  a `src/main/groovy` directory.  I've since added that and succesffuly created and run a Groovy script from that directory.

Answer (score 0):

I received an answer for IntelliJ tech support, see ticket https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/5849227.

In that ticket it was stated that the online documentation is out of date and the way to create a new Groovy Project has changed.

The following image shows how to create a new Groovy Project.

[image]

I verified that this solution did work.